# SQL Won't GROUP BY completely

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL code that originally worked great, but then I had to add a new item to a CASE, now my GROUP BY won't group completely together like before and it's messing up my calculations. I don't even want to group by the completed date, it's just there for a case, but my code blows up if I don't have it there.

EDIT: The original code worked great, but I had to add the completed date so I could add a CASE, then it errors if I don't add it to the GROUP BY, so I added it and now it doesn't group the way it did in the original code.
What this code does is take a bunch of information from other tables, it calculates how much someone owes, how much someone pays and spits out the difference.

**ORIGINAL CODE**

```
INSERT INTO #ThisReportAll (CustomerID,Year,OverdueBalance,YearSetupId)
SELECT t.CustomerId, ys.Name AS Year,SUM(t.TtlSpeciesCost) - Isnull(cp.TtlPayments,0) + Isnull(ba.Amount,0) 
AS TtlOwnerCost, t.YearSetupId AS YearSetupId
FROM #TotalAnimalCostAll t
LEFT JOIN #CustomerPaymentsAll cp ON t.CustomerId=cp.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN YearSetup ys ON t.YearSetupId = ys.YearSetupId
LEFT JOIN #BalanceAdjustmentsAll ba ON t.CustomerId=ba.CustomerID
GROUP BY t.CustomerId,ys.Name,cp.TtlPayments, ba.Amount, t.YearSetupId
```

**New Code that Doesn't Work All The Way**

```
INSERT INTO #ThisReportAll (CustomerID,Year,OverdueBalance,YearSetupId)
SELECT t.CustomerId, ys.Name AS Year, 
CASE 
        WHEN SUM(t.TtlSpeciesCost) < 5 AND t.Complete < CONVERT(DATE,'01-01-2017')
        THEN (5) - Isnull(cp.TtlPayments,0) + Isnull(ba.Amount,0) 
        ELSE SUM(t.TtlSpeciesCost) - Isnull(cp.TtlPayments,0) + Isnull(ba.Amount,0) 
END
AS TtlOwnerCost, t.YearSetupId AS YearSetupId
FROM #TotalAnimalCostAll t
LEFT JOIN #CustomerPaymentsAll cp ON t.CustomerId=cp.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN YearSetup ys ON t.YearSetupId = ys.YearSetupId
LEFT JOIN #BalanceAdjustmentsAll ba ON t.CustomerId=ba.CustomerID
GROUP BY t.CustomerId,ys.Name,cp.TtlPayments, ba.Amount, t.YearSetupId, t.Complete
```

Comment: I would suggest that you explain what the code is supposed to do.  Sample data and desired results can help.  Non-working code does not necessarily do a good job in communicating intentions.

Comment: Well... you added t.Complete to your group by. So it's not going to be the same grouping...

Comment: A `CASE` in your SELECT column expressions cannot affect a `GROUP BY` in the same SELECT (unless the `GROUP BY` has been edited also).  In this case you have edited the `GROUP BY`, which is what changed it's behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `Complete` to affect your `GROUP BY` you need to do your `CASE` in a subquery that doesn't select `Complete`.  Then you don't have that extra field in the data you're grouping.  Like this:

```
SELECT [whatever fields]
from
    (
    SELECT t.CustomerId, ys.Name AS Year, 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(t.TtlSpeciesCost) < 5 AND t.Complete < CONVERT(DATE,'01-01-2017')
        THEN (5) - Isnull(cp.TtlPayments,0) + Isnull(ba.Amount,0) 
        ELSE SUM(t.TtlSpeciesCost) - Isnull(cp.TtlPayments,0) + Isnull(ba.Amount,0) 
    END
    AS TtlOwnerCost, t.YearSetupId AS YearSetupId
    FROM #TotalAnimalCostAll t
    LEFT JOIN #CustomerPaymentsAll cp ON t.CustomerId=cp.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN YearSetup ys ON t.YearSetupId = ys.YearSetupId
    LEFT JOIN #BalanceAdjustmentsAll ba ON t.CustomerId=ba.CustomerID
    ) as a
GROUP BY a.CustomerId, a.Name,a.TtlPayments, a.Amount, a.YearSetupId
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you are also grouping by `t.Complete` in the new code, but not in the original code. Your results need to account for that, or they will be wrong.

It also seems strange to me that `Isnull(cp.TtlPayments,0) + Isnull(ba.Amount,0)` are in your CASE statement, but are not aggregates when the statement uses SUMs in other places.